# jQuery images rotate based on direction of cursor

Tags: jquery, html, image, rotation, image-rotation

So i have an [oven](http://renuoven.co.uk) that has knobs that rotate on mouse over. They unfortunately only go clockwise. Is there some way i can log which way the cursor enters the image, from the right or left and rotate it accordingly? I.E if from left, rotate clockwise, if from right, rotate anti-clockwise. That would make a nice feature. does jQuery handle such events well?

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('img.menuimg').rotate({
        bind: {
            mouseover: function () {
                $(this).rotate({
                    center: ["50%", "68%"],
                    animateTo: 100,
                })
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                $(this).rotate({
                    center: ["50%", "68%"],
                    animateTo: 0,
                })
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that allows the knobs to turn clockwise?

Comment: The knobs on the link don't even work for me on the latest version of Chrome. You should post your relevant code as Austen suggested

Comment: woah, i didnt get my replies by mail. Sorry.. the code is:

Comment: `$(window).load(function(){
$('img.menuimg').rotate({ 
   bind: { 
        mouseover : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({
  center: ["50%", "68%"],
  animateTo:100,
 })},
        mouseout : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({

center: ["50%", "68%"],
animateTo:0,

})
        }
     } 
   
});
});`

Comment: you will need to check the x position of the mouse when hovering the knobs. Compare the x with the previous x, you can figure out which way the mouse is moving that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOR REFERENCE:

After months of searching.. i came across this:

http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/DirectionAwareHoverEffect/

The snippets should help figure out direction awareness

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here at SO.  Try taking the relevant bits and adding them in context to your post.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I will update some code later on today. that link just shows my solution exactly.